# Is it positive or negative to say "good for you!"

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

I've recently noticed that Simon (member of American Got Talent Jury) regularly uses to say "good for you" to candidates that told their story and background prior to their audition. Actually it sounds that he is interested in the story and happy for the candidate. However, translating it into my native language this phrase is more negatively inked (like "Good for you, but I don't really care, now please go ahead").

Comment: In *British* English, "Good for you!" is usually sincere (speaker approves of what you've done, or what's happened to you). The now somewhat dated version "**Bully** for you!" is/was usually used ***sarcastically*** (speaker doesn't care about you or your circumstances). But bear in mind that it's primarily ***context*** that determines whether the utterance is sincere or sarcastic, not the choice between ***good*** and ***bully***.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase, by itself, is positive, and I'm sure that's the way Mr. Cowell means it. Like most things, it can be said in a sarcastic way, implying the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add as an interesting point, as a native Australian English speaker, I would have said that it's negative. We use the phrase here almost exclusively in the sarcastic sense. I don't watch much American TV, and I was surprised to hear a person (American) running a follow-along style video tutorial use the phrase as encouragement for the viewers. That's how I got here!